# Confusing SQL query, Virtual tables and self-joins

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-11

I am learning SQL, and I'm working with virtual tables, and self-joins, the table (name: SALESREPS) I'm working on is in the image.

[image]

The objective for the query is to find the employees with higher quota than their manager, but I'm having troubles to understand why, for this query

```
SELECT EMPL.NAME, EMPL.`QUOTA`, MNG.`QUOTA`
FROM `SALESREPS` EMPL, `SALESREPS` MNG
WHERE MNG.`EMPL_NUM` = EMPL.`MANAGER`
AND EMPL.`QUOTA` > MNG.`QUOTA`;
```

the output is:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| NAME        | QUOTA     | QUOTA     |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Mary Jones  | 300000.00 | 275000.00 |
| Larry Fitch | 350000.00 | 275000.00 |
| Bill Adams  | 350000.00 | 200000.00 |
| Dan Roberts | 300000.00 | 200000.00 |
| Paul Cruz   | 275000.00 | 200000.00 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Which is correct, that is what i want. But if i change the WHERE clause to

```
SELECT EMPL.NAME, EMPL.`QUOTA`, MNG.`QUOTA`
FROM `SALESREPS` MNG, `SALESREPS` EMPL
WHERE MNG.`MANAGER` = EMPL.`EMPL_NUM`
AND EMPL.`QUOTA` > MNG.`QUOTA`;
```

the output is:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| NAME        | QUOTA     | QUOTA     |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Sam Clarck  | 275000.00 | 200000.00 |
| Larry Fitch | 350000.00 | 300000.00 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Which is incorrect. And i can't understand why that happen. I'm just swapping the column I'm referencing in each virtual table (EMPL and MNG). I changed from

```
WHERE MNG.EMPL_NUM = EMPL.MANAGER
```

to

```
WHERE MNG.MANAGER = EMPL.EMPL_NUM
```

but the equality should yield the same result, however, it doesn't happen that way.

Comment: Please provide sample data as table with text, not as image. Or even better create a fiddle sample and share its url, so people can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: `WHERE MNG.MANAGER = EMPL.EMPL_NUM` is saying *"Join these tables where the manager's manager, is the employee"*. This is essentially giving you the opposite of what you want. When in doubt, run it with no conditions and `SELECT *` and you'll see the results of the join.

Comment: Also, if you are learning SQL you should be learning the ANSI SQL join syntax. The join syntax you are using has not been considered good practice for 30+ years, so if the resources you are using are teaching that join syntax you should really find more modern resources

Comment: Please use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 30 years!!!

Answer (score 4):

Given both examples include this same predicate expression:

```
EMPL.`QUOTA` > MNG.`QUOTA`
```

This:

```
WHERE MNG.EMPL_NUM = EMPL.MANAGER
```

is **NOT** the same as this:

```
WHERE MNG.MANAGER = EMPL.EMPL_NUM
```

Because it inverts the roles relative to which must now be greater than the other.

---

While I'm here, **NEVER** combine tables using this syntax:

```
 FROM `SALESREPS` EMPL, `SALESREPS` MNG
```

This has been obsolete since the release of the ANSI-92 standard **more than 30 years ago**. If you're learning from material that teaches it this way, *you should ditch that material*. It's not leading you in a good direction.

The **correct** way to write the query is like this:

```
SELECT EMPL.NAME, EMPL.`QUOTA`, MNG.`QUOTA`
FROM `SALESREPS` EMPL
INNER JOIN `SALESREPS` MNG ON MNG.`EMPL_NUM` = EMPL.`MANAGER`
WHERE EMPL.`QUOTA` > MNG.`QUOTA`;
```

Comment: Ok ok, yes, that makes sense. I am learning SQL using the book 'SQL The Complete Reference, 3rd Edition by James R. Groff and Paul N.', you think that book it's good? The book does say that it is more correct to use the join syntax but it also mentions these obsolete forms. I'll be more careful with deprecated syntaxes from now on, thank you very much. By the way, sorry for the misuse of the platform and for how I structured the question, it's my first time asking on a page :p Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it is very simple, if you really put this one table as two tables in your mind.

This is your the first variant, which one is very good and logically.
You satarted from employees, joined managers, checked differences in quota and put very clear columns for result - names from employees and quotes from both tables.
[Your first variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q07j.png)

But, your second variant is really confused, because you started from a wrong table, from managers, and put in the result data from employees:
[Your second variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSz7d.png)

So, in the second case, your task for the SQL server sounds like:
Please, show me those employees, who is the manager of managers (because you link table EMP to table MNG by manager's code, so you want to see, who is manager of each manager from the table), and show just those results, where quota manager of manager is bigger then for the manager itself.

So, if you want to be clear with yourself, just start SQL from logical point. Think, which tables shuld be on the left side, and how you should join all other tables step-by-step to this the very first table.
And please use join for joining =)

Comment: Yes, that what you said "So, in the second case, your task for the SQL server sounds like: Please, show me those employees, who is the manager of managers" is what I thought was happening, I just didn't understand why , but I'm clear now, thank you.  And thank you for being so kind ^⁠_⁠^